# Fazer requisição em um intervalo de tempo definido

Tags: java, android, retrofit

Meu aplicativo deve atualizar uma lista de dados que vem do servidor a cada 5 minutos. Usando Retrofit para requisição `HTTP`, qual a melhor maneira de fazer isso?

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar o recurso [Alarm](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html) do Android e definir de quanto em quanto tempo ele deve ser chamado.

Primeiro você precisa criar um **broadcast receiver** que será chamado quando o alarme for executado:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = AlarmReceiver.class.getSimpleName();

    public AlarmReceiver() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onReceive()");

        // Aqui você coloca o código que deve ser executado a cada X minutos
    }
}
```

Não esqueça de adicionar o receiver no seu arquivo *AndroidManifest.xml* (dentro da marcação application):

```
<receiver
    android:name=".AlarmReceiver"
    android:exported="false"></receiver>
```

Agora você precisa criar uma classe customizada que estenda a classe *Application* (caso você já não possua no seu app). Recomendo você criar o alarme dentro do método **onCreate**:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 300000, pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

Agora é só adicionar a classe customizada no *AndroidManifest.xml*:

```
<application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
```

Adicione a permissão **WAKE_LOCK** no *AndroidManifest.xml*:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Existem diversas formas de fazer isso, antes de optar por uma, é necessário conhecer o que cada uma nos oferece e escolher aquela que mais se adequa às nossas necessidade.

A principal vantagem do *Alarm* é que opera fora do contexto da sua aplicação, permitindo fazer a requisição, mesmo que a aplicação não esteja em execução.
No entanto, ela pode ser também a maior desvantagem. Depois de iniciar o *Alarm* ele irá fazer uma requisição a cada 5 minutos enquanto o dispositivo não for desligado, com o correspondente custo de bateria e recursos.

Caso apenas necessite de actualizar a lista enquanto a aplicação estiver a correr, não use um *Alarm*.

Nessa situação a utilização do *Timer* poderia ser uma possível opção.
No entanto, o código executado pelo *Timer* corre numa *background thread*, como o Retrofit também corre os seus métodos numa *Thread* própria, não faz sentido usar uma *background thread* para correr outra *background thread*.
Além de que teria de resolver o problema de os métodos `onResponse()` e `onFailure()` serem executados na *thread* criada pelo *Timer* e não na *UIThread*.
Por outro lado o Timer não deve ser utilizado em tarefas demoradas.

Assim, caso apenas necessite de actualizar a lista enquanto a aplicação estiver em execução, sugiro que utilize um *Handler*.

Declare um campo para guardar a referência ao *Handler*

```
private Handler handler;
```

No `onCreate()` crie o *Handler* e de imediato faça a requisição:

```
handler = new Handler();
handler.post(new UpdateData());
```

Para evitar *memory leaks* declare a classe UpdateData num arquivo java à parte ou como uma *static inner* classe da *Activity*.

```
private static final class UpdateData implements Runnable{
   @Override
   public void run() {
      //Faça aqui a requisição via Retrofit
      .....

      //agenda nova requisição daqui a 5 minutos
      handler.postDelayed(this, 5*60*1000);
   }
}
```

No método `onDestroy()` remova o pedido a novas requisições:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Um timer é mais fácil de ser implementado:

```
 private final Timer myTimer = new Timer();

     public class myClass {

     @Override
     public void onResume() {
            ...   
            myTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new myTask(), 0, (long) (18000000));  // Tempo em milisegundos.

        } 



        private class myTask extends TimerTask {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                ... execute os procedimentos.
            }
        }

    }
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15571169/i-need-help-understanding-the-scheduleatfixedrate-method-of-thetimer-class-in-ja

http://www.iitk.ac.in/esc101/05Aug/tutorial/essential/threads/timer.html