# Como correr uma tarefa em background

Tags: java, android

Eu sou novo em programação android e tenho estado a fazer uma aplicação para mim proprio até agora.
Nesta app quero que quando ela entrar em background, ou seja, quando sair da aplicação sem chamar o metodo onDestroy(), comece a ser executado uma tarefa.

Quando eu sair da aplicação começa um cronometrar 15 minutos, quando o tempo acabar será chamado um webservice para verificar se tenho algum alerta novo.

Gostava de saber se me podem indicar alguma library ou tutorial que possa utilizar

Comment: Eu acredito que seja melhor vc pesquisar sobre o [FireBase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client?hl=pt-br), ele serve exatamente pra isso

Comment: Veja [Fazer requisição em um intervalo de tempo definido](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/156271/2541)

Answer (score 1):

Ola,

Voce pode criar um service:

> Um Service é um componente do aplicativo que pode realizar operações longas e não fornece uma interface do usuário. Outro componente do aplicativo pode iniciar um serviço e ele continuará em execução em segundo plano mesmo que o usuário alterne para outro aplicativo. Além disso, um componente poderá se vincular a um serviço para interagir com ele e até estabelecer comunicação entre processos (IPC). Por exemplo, um serviço pode lidar com transações de rede, reproduzir música, executar E/S de arquivos, ou interagir com um provedor de conteúdo, tudo a partir do segundo plano....
>   https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Um exemplo simples para oque voce precisa:

Crie a classe do serviço

```
public class TarefaBackground extends IntentService {
    /**
     * Creates an IntentService.  Invoked by your subclass's constructor.
     *
     * @param name Used to name the worker thread, important only for debugging.
     */
    long seconds;
    public Sleeper(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    public Sleeper() {
        super("");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
        long millis = 900000;
        Toast.makeText(this, "OnHandle", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        while(true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(millis);
                System.out.println("executou ação");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Adicione dentro da tag Application no manifests

```
<service
    android:name=".TarefaBackground">
</service>
```

Por fim no mainActivity

```
@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Intent intent= new Intent(MainActivity.this,TarefaBackground.class);
        startService(intent);

    }
```